# How to create a function finding the last key of an array using value PHP in different ways

Tags: php

How to get the Cat by using the value `Nap` in array

```
["Dog" => "Bite", "Cat" => "Nap"]
```

and i want to get `Cat` using value `Nap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$key = array_search('Nap', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is not clear in your question is if you already know the entry is the last entry, or if you're searching for a value that is somewhere in your array.

- If you have PHP 7.3, and you know it's the last entry, you can use `array_key_last()` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php )
- `$key = array_search('Nap', $array);` (as mentionned by @Sanu0786 )

Comment: I just started to learn programming language ..

Comment: Did that give you the answer your expected @EfrenBontuyan? if yes, please press on the ✓ next to my answer in order to accept it...